# PolymerJS: Multiple events fire for same action (on-blur when on-submit)

Tags: javascript, events, polymer

I have this input form and I want to save the value of the input whenever the user either fires an `on-submit` **or** an `on-blur` event.

And I have the problem, that whenever the user fires the `on-submit`, naturally the `on-blur` event is also fired. Thus **two** events with the same content is fired. (Not a big problem, but still).

I've searched for solutions and found a lot for `jQuery`, and I believe that I need a raw `javascript` solution for this.

**Here is my form:**

```
<form method="post" on-submit="doneEditAction">
    <input 
        type="text" 
        value="{{editValue::input}}"
        id="editItemInputField"
        on-keyup="editKeyupAction"
        on-blur="editBlur">
    <button type="submit">edit</button>
</form>
```

This form fires the `doneEditAction` event when I submit the form. But at the same time the `editBlur` event gets also fired, which should do the same as the `doneEditAction` event, to save the value of the input.

**editBlur** Event

```
editBlur: function (e) {
    this.doneEditAction(e);

    this.editing = false;
}
```

**doneEditAction** Event

```
doneEditAction: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.editingValue);

    this.editing = false;
}
```

---

**HERE ARE MY QUESTIONS:**

1. How do I make the form not fire the `on-blur` event, when the form is submitted? Or
2. How do I make the form fire always only one event? Or, see edit,
3. Does it even matter at all (from a performance perspective) if two identical events are fired?

---

**EDIT**

Just saw that the [Polymer TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/examples/polymer/index.html) and they also fire **two** events when you try to edit it. Proof: [image: Screenshot of DevTools]

Does that mean, that it actually doesn't matter, if **two** same events are fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `on-blur` event fires automatically everytime the `on-submit` event is fired, the `doneEdit` event handler is executed twice.

And since the `doneEdit` event handler sets the `editing` property to `false` **twice**, there is a simple solution to make sure the `doneEdit` event is executed only once.

In `doneEdit` we check if the `editing` is `true` and only then perform any action we want, setting the `editing` value to `false`.

```
doneEdit(function) {
    if(this.editing === true) {
        this.editing = false;
        console.log(this.editingValue);
    }
}
```

Thus when the `doneEdit` handler will be called the second time due to the `on-blur` event, `this.editing` is already set to `false` and `console.log()` is not executed twice.

Thanks to the PolymerTodoMVC source code.